# How to using from ContextMenu in a gridCell?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a CustomControl like this:

```
        <Button Name="b"  Height="20" Click="b_Click"  Content="operation" Width="60">
         <Button.ContextMenu> 
             <ContextMenu>

                <MenuItem Header="Copy"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="cut"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="delete"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
         </Button.ContextMenu> 

        </Button>
```

in CodeBehind ia have :

```
   if (b.ContextMenu != null && b.ContextMenu.IsOpen == false)
               {
                    b.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = b;
                    b.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
                   ContextMenuService.SetPlacement(b, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom);
                   b.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;//I have error in this Line
                }
```

I use from my conrol in a DataGrid Cell ...when i click on my button i get an error in this line

```
 b.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
```

> "ContextMenu" cannot have logical or visual parent

how can i resolve this erorr

Comment: Why you are doing this:
                    b.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = b;
                    b.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
                   ContextMenuService.SetPlacement(b, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom);

Answer (score 0):

A sample of working app, hope this gives you required clue...

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,0,195,72" x:Name="A"> 
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="cut" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="delete" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}">
                                           </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding}">

                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```